# How do I maximize the market share of my console?

Tags: mad-games-tycoon

When I develop my own console I never seem to get above 1-2% market share.

I've tried marketing it so that hype is at maximum, lowering licensing cost and developing exclusive titles for it.

What else can I do to maximize my console's market share?

Answer (score 1):

According to the Mad Games Tycoon [wiki](http://mad-games-tycoon.wikia.com/wiki/Console_Development_(Room)):

> Gaining market share for your console depends on releasing good games for it (it can be on other platforms too), having a lot of fans, showcasing it at the annual convention, and of course, marketing.

So possibly gaining fans and a convention display could be other things to try.

Comment: Does it just depend on me releasing games for it or also other developers? How do I get other developers to release games for my console?